# iOS equivalent to XAML spy and web inspectors?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, utility, xamarin-studio

When developing XAML apps I utilized XAML spy which allows me to inspect the rendered app elements when running the app in the simulator. It aids in finding where certain styling is emanating from. It's similar to developer consoles in web browsers and in particular Firebug in Firefox.

Is there an equivalent tool for iOS development that I can use while running my app in the iPhoneSimulator from Xamarin Studio?

Answer (score 2):

I would give [Reveal](http://revealapp.com/) a go. It allows you to inspect and debug your UI and autolayout issues similar to XAML spy.

If you are using Xamarin there is a getting started [guide](http://support.revealapp.com/kb/getting-started/xamarin-getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but http://sparkinspector.com/ is the closest i've seen.

Answer (score 0):

I have found something that can be used for some limited inspecting of elements - **Accessibility Inspector.**

**Enabling the iOS Accessibility Inspector:**

- Start **simulator** > click **Home** button to return to home screen > start **Settings** app > nav to **General, Accessibility** and turn it on

It adds an overlay to the screen showing label, traits, frame and notification details.

It's not as extensive as I was after.